# make*** No rule to make target 'obj_sky/neighbour-attr.o' contiki-cooja simulation error

Tags: compiler-errors, operating-system, contiki, cooja

I am trying to compile an example code in cooja simulator on contiki-2.7 Operating System. Contiki is an OS for IoT applications. Before implementing in hardware the code is tested in cooja simulator first.

For a research purpose I installed contiki-2.7 in virtual box and trying to execute some codes in cooja simulator.

But i can't compile any examples code for this simulation.

**For compilation of any code the simulator shows me the error**

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this error. It is very important for me. I am not getting enough resource in google.

*Thanks in Advance.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means,
to compile your program you need some necessary packages installation in your system. 
For example:
As your code is written in C programming language you need to install gcc to compile it.
Similarly, 
You may need gcc-msp430, msp430-libc, gcc-avr, binutils-avr  etc packages.

To install these packages hit the following apt command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential binutils-msp430 gcc-msp430  msp430-libc binutils-avr gcc-avr gdb-avr avr-libc  avrdude openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre ant libncurses5-dev doxygen git
```

[For You : The Reference is 
http://sens-space.blogspot.com/2014/11/contki-and-cooja-installation-in-ubuntu.html
]